# Ruby on rails fetch the multiple values stored in the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column in record which is `looking_job` in which i am storing multple values, by seeing into the parameters i get

```
looking_job: "[\"office\", \"fieldwork\"]"
```

this columne is stored in the profiles table

so that

```
@profile = Profile.where(individual_id: params[:individual_id]).first
```

when i print the

```
<%= @profile.looking_job  %>
```

in the view i am getting the output as 
["office", "fieldwork"]

but i want it to show like - office, fieldwork

how can i get it ? thankx in advance

Comment: use  @profile.looking_job.join(",")

Comment: but when i fetch from @profile.looking_job this is already converted into string and join is a method for array

Comment: as you must know we can never get  '["office", "fieldwork"]' in the browser
but this ["office", "fieldwork"] and when i apply join method this is what i get -

undefined method `join' for "[\"office\", \"fieldwork\"]":String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
▶ looking_job = "[\"office\", \"fieldwork\"]"
#⇒ "[\"office\", \"fieldwork\"]"
▶ require 'json'
#⇒ true
▶ JSON.parse(looking_job).join(', ')
#⇒ "office, fieldwork"
```

Comment: i am getting require 'json' as false